# Ruby: split string on parentheses and space

Tags: regex, ruby, space, parentheses

I want to use RegEx to split a string with space and parentheses

Example:

> "The (New York city) :) is big"

=> Output:

> ["The", "New York city", ":)", "is", "big"]

I have tried this expression: `/\([^\)]+?[\)]|[^ ]+/`

but the parentheses are still there so not good.

> ["The", "(New York city)", ":)", "is", "big"]

Has somebody any idea, please ?
Thanks

Comment: Does `(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))|[^\s()]\S*` work better? Can you have something like `(:-|`?  What would be the expected behavior?

Comment: Thank you for question. " (:-" should be kept together  "(:-"

Comment: Ok, so the solution in my answer suits your scenario better.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can capture the parts you need and then, after applying `scan`, subtract all `nil` array items (that will occur since every match will only have a single capturing group value filled):

```rb
text = "The (New York city) :) is big"
arr = text.scan(/\(([^()]+)\)|(\S+)/).flatten - [nil]
# Or 
# arr = text.scan(/\(([^()]+)\)|(\S+)/).flatten.compact
p arr # => ["The", "New York city", ":)", "is", "big"]
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/4YsgJO) and the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/zx01kfqCSey755).

*Details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` -  a `)` char
- `|` - or
- `(\S+)` - Group 2: one or more non-whitespace chars.

Comment: Thank you for your solution which is working. I wonder whether it is possible to have another Reg Expression without returning (nil)

Comment: @BTam I do not think there is a safe pattern like that. I'd use my solution here.

Comment: @Wiktor_Stribiżew, have you any idea not to mach the parentheses between another one, please ? "(New York and (New Orelans) cities ) are big" woud returns
["New York and New Orelans cities", "are", "big"]

Comment: @BTam Not sure it is possible to safely do that all with just one regex, see [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/K0EaKK). If you have no `(` and `)` inside the parentheses, it should work. Basically, it is `text.scan(/(\((?:[^()]++|\g<1>)*\))|(\S+)/).map {|x| [x[0] != nil ? x[0].gsub(/[()]+/, "").strip : x[0], x[1]]}.flatten.compact`

Answer (score -1):

One may write:

```
str = "The (New York city) :) is big"
```

```
str.gsub(/\(.*?\)|\S+/).with_object([]) do |s,a|
  a << (s[0]=='(' && s[-1] == ')' ? s[1..-2] : s)
end
  #=> ["The", "(New York City)", ":)", "is", "big"]
```

This uses the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes one argument--here a regular expression--and no block, returning an enumerator:

```
enum = str.gsub(/\(.*?\)|\S+/)
  #=> #<Enumerator: "The (New York City) :) is big":gsub(/\(.*?\)|\S+/)>
```

​We can see the (string) objects that will be generated by the enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> ["The", "(New York City)", ":)", "is", "big"]
```

We can make the regular expression self-documenting by expressing it in *free-spacing* mode:

```
/
\(    # match '('
.*?   # match zero or more characters, lazily
\)    # match ')'
|     # or
\S+   # match one or more characters other than white spaces
/x    # free-spacing regex definition mode
```